How did you know I ran/ have run a marathon?
I encountered a sentence like this in a story, B ran a marathon quite a long time ago:

A: I tried/ have tried a training for a marathon, but I failed. Could
you give me some of your experience?
B: (She is surprised) How did you know I ran a marathon?

(1) How did you know I ran a marathon?
But I think that I can use present perfect "have run" stead to express that running a marathon is my life experience:
(2) How did you know I have run a marathon?
But let see, visiting Paris is also a life experience, but we can use (4), but can't use (3). Why?

A: I would like to visit Paris. Could you tell me more about Paris?
B:How did you know I.....to Paris?

(3) How did you know I was in to Paris?
(4) How did you know I have been to Paris?

As a British English speaker I would find (2) more natural than (1). A comparable way of saying (3) would be "How the heck did you know I went to Paris?", not "was in to".

3 is ungrammatical. Either How did you know I was / have been in Paris, or How did you know I went / have been to Paris.

"How did you know I went to Paris?"=>This sentence is also acceptable to use to refer to someone's experience. Right?

"I went to Paris" is a past "act" not an accumulation of experience.  How did you know I ran a marathon is asking "How did you know that I did that?"  How did you know I've run a marathon? is asking "How did you know that running a marathon is one of the things I've done?"

A minor side note: You meant not let see, but let’s see. Perhaps you had heard the phrase but never seen it written, and thus mis-analyzed it?

Present perfect makes sense if it relates to the present; simple past if it relates to something else in the past. Same as any other usage.

There are many ways to refer to an event in the past, and you might use different wording to respond to specific questions, to convey a specific time or whether something is still ongoing. But in the example of having run a marathon, all of the phrasings below say the same thing -- the event happened and concluded in the past:
How did you know that...
I did run a marathon.
I have run a marathon.
I ran a marathon.
I was in a marathon.
I completed a marathon.
I have completed a marathon (at some time in the past).
I had completed a marathon (and then something else happened).
I did complete a marathon.
I did a marathon (colloq.)
I have been in a marathon (maybe more than one).
I was a marathon runner.
I had been in a marathon.

But why can’t we use “How did you know that I went to Paris?”

But you can use that expression. Why do you think you cannot?

@LE123 was in Paris, went to Paris, but not was in to Paris.
